# joomla 2.5 : list links to articles in 2 columns

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla! 2.5 website, and I have to add a lightbox popup that will contain links to all articles from a specific category(+subs).

If anyone can suggest all-in-one solution, that will be great! But generally I'm asking, **how to list links to all articles from a specific category and its sub-categories in two/three columns?**

I know I can set **Category blog View** to output only article links, without full/introtext, but in this case links will all be *in one column*. I need *at least two*.

*A possibility of grouping article links by subcategory would be great as well (but this is the thing I can live without).*

How can this be done?

I'm looking for:

- a standard way of configuring this
- Template override (I'm using T3
  framework)
- Custom extension
- any other method ...

Answer (score 2):

When I first read your question I said: "Wow, that's pretty easy", because I'm used to working with [K2](http://getk2.org) instead of Joomla's content component.

There is a module that can show the articles from a specific category: [DM Article List Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/11737) but you still need to create/modify the template almost the same way you would do with Joomla's content component.

To give you an idea, this is the code section that handles the generation of columns to show the article links in K2:

```
        <?php foreach($this->links as $key=>$item): ?>

        <?php
        // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row
        if( (($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_links_columns'))==0) || count($this->links)<$this->params->get('num_links_columns') )
            $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';
        else
            $lastContainer='';
        ?>

        <div class="itemContainer<?php echo $lastContainer; ?>"<?php echo (count($this->links)==1) ? '' : ' style="width:'.number_format(100/$this->params->get('num_links_columns'), 1).'%;"'; ?>>
            <?php
                // Load category_item_links.php by default
                $this->item=$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item_links');
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php if(($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_links_columns'))==0): ?>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```